# Precision of replicated measurements on the same subject

Tags: statistical-significance, repeated-measures

I have developed a technique to count bacteria on a petri dish. Previously these bacteria could not be counted, so there is no reference standerd to compare our measurements with. To show the preciseness of my method I thought it was a good idea to do replicated measurements.

Therefor I measured the same 200 petri dishes three times using my technique. The amount of bacteria did not change between measurements. The measurements are continues and not normally distributed.

Our dataset looks like this:

```
     M1       M2       M3
 34,543   34,500   35,001
  0,002    0,002    0,002
231,003  230,974  231,509
  9,456    9,693    9,543
 35,543   35,500   35,001
  0,034    0,035    0,035
 31,603   30,674   31,609
  40,456   39,693   39,543
   etc
```

I want to know if my new method is consistent. How can I test that my three measurements of the same 200 samples do not differ significantly?

If it implies a statistical test (e.g. repeated measures anova), would a p>0.05 be enough to enforce my claim?

Comment: Changed 'replicated' to 'repeated' as these are not the same in statistics.

Answer (score 1):

You ask: How can I test that my three measurements of the same 200 samples do not differ?

But of course they differ. In each row, the three replicates are not identical. If the question is "Do they differ?", then the answer is yes. No calculations needed.

It seems to me that your real question is: How much do the replicates vary? Once you think about it that way, you'll think of a few ways to answer that question as a number.

You attached the tags "statistical significance" and "repeated measures" but I don't see how either of these concepts apply to your situation.

Comment: Replicate measurements would indeed be the correct jargon. My non-statistical and non-english tongue abandoned me when writing the question. But what to do now?

Comment: @CousinCocaine. Now we need to understand what your scientific question is. Avoid the word "significantly' which often gets i the way of clear thinking. What question do you want to ask. Clearly the different rows vary a lot, and the replicates in each row vary a bit. What calculation would be helpful?